# Trying to animate one UIImageView with two animations, only one animation has duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cgaffinetransform

What I want to do is flip this `UIImageView` in an instant, no animation, then I need it to `float` to it's intended position on the screen. Both of the `transformations` are working, but not the way I want them to.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
resultsEnemy.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];

resultsEnemy.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

This is the code I am using. Despite the fact that the scale code (which I am using to flip the `UIImageView`) is not part of the animation with the 0.5 `duration`, it is following those rules. How do I avoid this?

Comment: What if you put the transform *before* the animation block?

Comment: When you apply two tranform, you need to create only one (for example with makeTranslation) and the second you have to apply to the current CGAffineTransformRotate(resultsEnemy.transform,... otherwise with the second transform you completly override the first one

Answer (score 0):

Applying two transforms like that isn't going to produce the result you expect. What you need to do is combine them into a single transform matrix. The following should work as expected.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

// Create two separate transforms and concatenate them together.
// Use that new transform matrix to accomplish both transforms at once.
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
resultsEnemy.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

---

Edit: Based off of your clarification, you seem to be wanting something like this:

```
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
resultsEnemy.transform = scale;
[CATransaction commit];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

resultsEnemy.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: But that isn't what I want to do. I want the scale to have no duration, but I want the translate to have a 0.5 duration. I do not want them both to have a duration.

Comment: @mguniverse: See my edit. If that doesn't work, remove the begin/commit and add `[CATransaction flush];` after you set the scale transform.